# object.onclick is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I've been searching through forums for the past few hours and can't seem to figure out why I my *onclick* method isn't working properly.

For context, I'm trying to get this code to output something in the console when a button is clicked.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("next").onclick = function test() {
  console.log("hello");
}
```

Here are my next/previous buttons:

```
<!-- Next and previous buttons -->
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
```

The code I'm using was referenced from w3schools, although I modified it slightly. Here's the entirety of it:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  </head>

  <body onload="getInformation(), showSlides()">
    <!-- Slideshow container -->
    <div class="slideshow-container">

    <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"
       style="width:100%">
      <div class="text"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/730896/pexels-photo-730896.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"
       style="width:100%">
      <div class="text"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/57416/cat-sweet-kitty-animals-57416.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"
       style="width:100%">
      <div class="text"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/569170/pexels-photo-569170.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"
       style="width:100%">
      <div class="text"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/271955/pexels-photo-271955.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"
       style="width:100%">
      <div class="text"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- The dots/circles -->
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html {
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

Javascript

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function getInformation() {
  console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("prev")[0].innerHTML);
  console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("next")[0].innerHTML);
}

function updateInformation() {
  console.log("The current slide is: " + slideIndex);
  // console.log("Value in array is: " + [slideIndex-1]);
}

document.getElementsByClassName("next") = function test() {
  console.log("hello");
}

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";

  updateInformation();
}
```

If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it. Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getElementsBy* methods return HTMLCollections, which can be difficult to work with  - and also, they're *collections*, not individual elements, so you'd have to select an individual element from it first before attaching a listener to the element. Consider using querySelectorAll instead, which returns a static NodeList - unlike an HTMLCollection, it can be iterated over directly, it won't change while it's being iterated over, and it's much more flexible.

Or if you're only selecting a single element, use `querySelector` instead:

```
document.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click', function test() {
  console.log("hello");
});
```

Avoid inline handlers (which are as bad as `eval`) and `onclick`, which restricts you to one listener of a type per element - use `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems like what you suggested didn't work, or I may not have used it correctly. The console isn't giving me any indication that the button was clicked.

Comment: See here: https://jsfiddle.net/wv9h0yge/ Must be on your end if that doesn't work

Comment: I finally understand my issue. The DOM object doesn't get referenced unless it's embedded in a function. I thought it would be its own function that gets called on whenever the event occurs, but it seems to work within a script tag or in one of my other js functions.